# How to replace a long input-processing pipe by a script?

Tags: perl, bash

I have a long shell command, something like this:

```
cat file \
  | perl -pe 's/...//g' \
  | grep -v "hehe" \
  | $HOME/scripts/foo.pl \
  | sort | uniq -c
```

Now I'd like to put the whole pipe into a script `script.sh`, so that the command becomes:

```
cat file | ./script.sh
```

Ideally, the script should then also be callable like that:

```
./script.sh file
```

But how do I write that script? It seems not straightforward at all to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: As a note on style, an expression like `cat file | ./script.sh` is sometimes known as a ["Useless Use of cat"](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat), since you can just write `./script.sh < file`.  (There are some similar useful tips on that page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

content of script.sh:

`cat $1 \

| perl -pe 's/...//g' \

| grep -v "hehe" \

| $HOME/scripts/foo.pl \

| sort | uniq -c`

And then run it as `./script.sh file`.

Should do the trick.

Note the `$1` that references the first (and only) command line parameter.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Just the `cat file | ./script.sh` won't work, which would be nice. Especially because I often have to do `head file | ./script.sh`. A workaround is `./script.sh <(head file)` in `bash`, but it's not as nice.

Comment: it might be worth adding (a) a shebang line and (b) some explanation of what happens when no command-line parameter is supplied (i.e. `cat` has no argument so uses stdin).  @Frank could also make it explicit with `./script -` to use stdin since `cat` understands `-` to mean "use standard input".

Answer (score 0):

Combining some simple shell with a little Perl DWIMery and you can make your script do the right thing.

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -pe 's/...//g' "$@" \
  | grep -v "hehe" \
  | $HOME/scripts/foo.pl \
  | sort | uniq -c
```

You can run this as `./script.sh file` and it will read `file` or as `grep foo file | ./script.sh` and it will read from `STDIN`. In bash and some other shells `"$@"` expands to the list of quoted arguments, or nothing if there are no arguments. When `perl` doesn't have any file arguments it will read by default from `STDIN`.